# Android adb Unable to pull from emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to pull a ***screen-capture from emulator*** using following command and getting an error displayed below the command :-

```
$ adb shell pull /sdcard/screencap.png
```

**Error :-**

```
/system/bin/sh: pull: not found
```

screencapture is working and I can see the file on the emulator. I have setup the android sdk path in in my `.bashrc` as :-

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`adb pull`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#copyfiles), not `adb shell pull`.